# Laravel and Redis Cache updating without flushing

Tags: laravel, caching, redis

I'm having trouble finding an answer with the possibility of adding a new record to my cache without having to flush the entire cache.

I currently use the file driver for laravel and whenever a new sale comes in flush the cache and then use Cache::remember, however this is not ideal as it slows down access to the index greatly.

I have installed redis in an attempt to speed the process up.  Can I simply add a new sale to the existing cache without flushing it and reloading?

Comment: Sure, you can add a new cache key (or update an existing one) at any time without flushing everything else. I feel like I'm missing something - is there a reason you think this isn't possible? Is there some complication you haven't explained?

Comment: No reason to think it isn't possible, just wanted to clarify before I started moving over to redis.  Is this also possible with the file cache driver?

Comment: It's possible with all the cache drivers. They've all got `Cache::forget` to clear out an individual key, and `Cache::remember` for an already-existing key will update its value. If you ever *want* it to fail if the key already exists, look at `Cache::add`.